# member varibables are not staying initialized

Tags: c++

I wrote a class called Stock and have a default constructor that initializes all the member variables but when I use those variables in other functions, it spits out random numbers.

```
class Stock
{
private:
   int numStocks;
   int numBought;
   int sellHistory;
   int soldShares;
   int size;

   float stockPrice;
   float soldPrice;
   float profit;

   queue<float>  stocks;
   vector<int>   numSharesBought;
   vector<int>   sharePrice;


public:
   Stock()
   {

   int numStocks = 0;
   int numBought = 0;
   int sellHistory = 0;
   int soldShares = 0;
   int size = 0;

   float stockPrice = 0.0;
   float soldPrice = 0.0;
   float soldPrice = 0.0;
   float profit = 0.0;

   cout << "Sell History" << sellHistory << endl;

   }
```

here's one of my functions that I am using the member variables in:

```
void Stock::sellStocks()
{

   float proceeds = 0.0;
   queue<float> stockProceeds;


   cout << "> Sell ";
   cin >> soldShares >> soldPrice;

   //add up the dollar amount of the number of shares being sold                   \

   for( int i = 0; i < soldShares; i++)
   {
      proceeds = proceeds + stocks.front();
      stockProceeds.push(stocks.front());
      stocks.pop();
   }

   //you've made a sell. add one to the sell history.                              \

   sellHistory = sellHistory + 1;

   cout << "sell History: " << sellHistory << endl;
   //calculate the profit of the sold shares                                       \

   profit = (soldShares * soldPrice) - proceeds;
```

so, for instance, when I cout sellPrice in the default constructor it will say it equals zero, but when I cout sellPrice in the sellStock() function it spits out a random number. Can you see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `int numStocks = 0;` declares a local variable that just happens to have the same name as the member. It doesn't initialize the member

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int numStocks = 0;` and others declare new variables and initialize them, which shadow the class members. What you meant to do is `numStocks = 0;`(without `int`). Note that [member initializer lists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) are the preferred way of initializing variables in C++:

```
Stock()
  : numStocks{0}
  , numBought{0}
  , sellHistory{0}
  , soldShares{0}
  , size{0}
  , stockPrice{0.0}
  , soldPrice{0.0}
  , soldPrice{0.0}
  , profit{0.0}
{
  cout << "Sell History" << sellHistory << endl;
}
```